# SSL error with MariaDB and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, mariadb

I got a problem. I am trying to create an SSL connection between my MariaDB database and my PHP code. At the moment of making the connection it works well to a certain extent, since in the PHP errors I start to get the following error: **MySQL Server has gone away** and the number of failed attempts and connection abortions increase drastically.

This is my code:

```
$this->connection = mysqli_init();

mysqli_options($this->connection, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);

$this->connection->ssl_set('/xxx/xxx/client-key.pem', '/xxx/xx/client-cert.pem', '/xx/xxx/ca-cert.pem', NULL, NULL);

if (!$this->connection->real_connect($this->host, $this->user_db, $this->password_db, $this->database, 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL)) {
    $this->error_connect = $this->connection->connect_error;
    return false;
} else {
    $this->setCharset();
    return true;
}
```

What could be wrong with the server or my code?

Comment: You should use either the object-oriented `mysqli` interface or the procedural one, not both. Since you are using objects already the object-oriented one would be a better fit, so replace `mysqli_init` with the equivalent `new mysqli(...)` call.

Comment: But in the PHP documentation it says that to create mysqli_real_connect() you need a valid object that has been created by the mysqli_init() function. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php

Comment: You rarely see `mysqli_init()` in production code because nobody uses `real_connect`. I'm not even sure why that thing is in there, but `mysqli` is old and has a very confused history. Just use [`new mysqli(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) where you should be able to [set the necessary options](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php).

Comment: For SSL connections in the PHP documentation it is mandatory to start the connection that way because for new MySQLi does not let you use mysqli_options, the following error is displayed: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::mysqli_options()

Comment: Are you really committed to `mysqli`? [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) is a more robust interface and has much better support for TLS connections.

Comment: "But the PHP manual says..." -- Well, it is loosy-goosy on "mysqli_foo" vs "mysqli::foo" vs "obj->foo" -- We are just supposed to know that they meant "new".